# What are the basics in writing a program in Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am an undergrad in ICE. I was searching for ideas to do mini projects on and found this Arduino boards and programs. So actually what are the basics to develop our own gadgets? Any guidelines...?

Comment: I suggest you Google for some ideas, blogs, tutorials, etc. Your question is basically asking us to summarize hundreds, if not thousands, of web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some excellent books available as well as videos and articles on the Internet which will walk you through basic projects.  The most common method of programming is to use the free [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) which will talk to the board from your Mac or PC.  You can run the board straight from the USB port's power, or from an external source if you need it to be portable.

The programming language is very similar to C.  The program structure is basically a setup portion and then a continuous main loop that runs until the board is powered off.

If you want to experiment without actually purchasing one, there are some emulators available which will let you build entire project on a virtual breadboard before buying any actual components.  [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/) is a great board planner that you can install, or if you would rather, you can use [123D Circuits](https://123d.circuits.io/) from your web browser which will let you edit and simulated the circuits.

Basic knowledge of electrical circuits will be helpful for getting started, and is a great asset when designing larger projects.